# Changing background of button via Selector

Tags: android, button, selector

I have a buttons and i want when clicked on the button, the button changed image. I think everything is ok but when clicked on the button, background button changed for one moment(while i select this) and then the background button be first background color :( What is my problem??

contact_selector.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/contactpress"></item>
<item 
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/contactpress"></item>
<item 
    android:drawable="@drawable/contact"></item>
</selector>
```

activity_test.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_above="@id/btn"></FrameLayout>
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/contact_selector"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/contactpress" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/contactpress" android:state_focused="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/contact" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/contactpress" android:state_enabled="false"></item>

</selector>
```